# UnsatisfiedLinkError - What can this error mean? Every hint is useful!

Tags: java, exception

In Eclipse I get this eror:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.util.SharedObjects.nativeSetTable(Ljava/util/Hashtable;)Ljava/util/Hashtable;

I can see SharedObjects, but nativeSetTable doesn't seem to be a method. It might however be hidden -> I don't have access to the source code.

This was my code:

```
connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(this.url);
```

This is the trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.util.SharedObjects.nativeSetTable(Ljava/util/Hashtable;)Ljava/util/Hashtable;
>     at
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.util.SharedObjects.nativeSetTable(Native
>   Method)   at
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.util.SharedObjects.createTable(SharedObjects.java:465)
>     at
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.util.SharedObjects.(SharedObjects.java:181)
>     at
>   com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.io.GeneralSharedIO.(GeneralSharedIO.java:67)
>     at
>   com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.checkForPermission(ConnectionBaseAdapter.java:236)
>     at
>   com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.openPrim(ConnectionBaseAdapter.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.openPrim(ConnectionBaseAdapter.java:178)
>     at
>   com.sun.midp.io.InternalConnector.openPrim(InternalConnector.java:254)
>     at
>   com.sun.midp.io.InternalConnector.open(InternalConnector.java:153)
>     at
>   javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:138)
>     at
>   javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:120)
>     at
>   javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:104)

Answer (score 1):

I think that `nativeSetTable()` is protected or private, that's why you don't see it. And moreover `nativeSetTable()` is a native method, which means that it is based on native code (already compiled for a specific processor and available in a specific lib [ie. a DLL]).

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that this particular method couldn't be retrieved and executed properly.

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

This means that your Java ME emulator must have missing librairies. You should try to reinstall it.

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - `UnsatisfiedLinkError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html)

Comment: What should I re-install? the library? The Java ME emulator? I installed it like this: http://howto-programming.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-installconfigure-eclipse-for.html

Comment: Well, if the method is private/protected and you can't invoke it, that must mean that your Nokia SDK installation/configuration is buggy one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are coupling your source code with the wrong version of the nokia mid library.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your runtime classpath is using a different version of the jar where SharedObjects lives, when compared to your compile-time classpath in Eclipse.  I would double-check your classpath settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one reason:

I created a test class in java to test my code, just a plain java file (with main method). And I ran it as a plain java application. Then, it doesn't work. But after I tried it in a Midlet, I didn't get the error!